# Simple notation question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

> Let A = {2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9} and define a relation R on A as follows:
>   For all x, y ∈ A, x R y ⇔ 3 | (x − y).
>
> Then 2 R 2 because 2 − 2 = 0, and 3 | 0.

What does the `3 | 0` notation mean here?

Comment: $a \mid b$ means that $a$ divides $b$, i.e. there is an integer $k$ with $b = k\cdot a$.

Comment: in number theory it is the notation for divisibility.  3|0 says that 3 divides 0.  3|6 means that 3 divides 6.  THe property described above is reflexivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\;3\mid 0\; $ = three divides zero, which means there exists an integer $\;k\;$ s.t.

$$0=3\cdot k$$

Can you see what integer $\;k\;$ fulfills the above?

Answer (score 2):

It means 3 divides 0. ${}{}{}$